# How to trigger a button to appear only if multiple options from different drop-down menus have been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make sure a "Done" button pops up after options from 3 separate drop-down menus have been selected (regardless of the specific choices). The button should only appear after all 3 drop-down menus have changed (from no selection to any selection).

Here's my HTML code:

```
{{# sentPt1 }}
    <div class="sent nodisplay">
    <p class="answer-container dropdown-container">
        <p class="question">
        <select id="response-quant" class="option" name="answer">
            <option disabled selected></option>
            <option value={{ QUANT1 }}>{{ QUANT1 }}</option>
            <option value={{ QUANT2 }}>{{ QUANT2 }}</option>
        </select>
        {{ sentPt1 }}
        <select id="response-shape" class="option" name="answer">
            <option disabled selected></option>
            <option value={{ SHAPE1 }}>{{ SHAPE1 }}</option>
            <option value={{ SHAPE2 }}>{{ SHAPE2 }}</option>
            <option value={{ SHAPE3 }}>{{ SHAPE3 }}</option>
        </select>
        {{ sentPt2 }}
        <select id="response-col" class="option" name="answer">
            <option disabled selected></option>
            <option value={{ COL1 }}>{{ COL1 }}</option>
            <option value={{ COL2 }}>{{ COL2 }}</option>
        </select>
        {{ sentPt3 }}
        </p>
        <button id="done" class="nodisplay" onchange="doneChange">Done</button>
    </p>
    </div>
{{/ sentPt1 }}
```

And here's the JS/ jQuery part (which of course is not really working for the time being):

```
$('#response-quant, #response-shape, # response-col').change(function() {
    $('#done').removeClass('nodisplay');
});
```

I would really like to find a jQuery solution which allows me to keep the structure I have so far. I've tried targeting the #id, the .class, and many other different options.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Nop. My main issue is that depending on how I code it either the button doesn't pop up at all or it pops up after the 1st/ only one choice has been made. I want to ensure people don't skip any choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should do something with `.each()`, like this working snippet:
(See comments in my code)

```js
$('.option').change(function() {
  $('#done').removeClass('nodisplay');  // By default, remove the class.
  $('.option').each(function() {        // Then, for each .option…
    if (!$(this).val()) {               // … if there's no option selected …
      $('#done').addClass('nodisplay'); // … add class,
      return;                           // … and stop loop!
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.nodisplay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{{# sentPt1 }}
<div class="sent">
  <div class="answer-container dropdown-container">
    <p class="question">
      <select id="response-quant" class="option" name="answer">
        <option disabled selected></option>
        <option value={{ QUANT1 }}>{{ QUANT1 }}</option>
        <option value={{ QUANT2 }}>{{ QUANT2 }}</option>
      </select>
      {{ sentPt1 }}
      <select id="response-shape" class="option" name="answer">
        <option disabled selected></option>
        <option value={{ SHAPE1 }}>{{ SHAPE1 }}</option>
        <option value={{ SHAPE2 }}>{{ SHAPE2 }}</option>
        <option value={{ SHAPE3 }}>{{ SHAPE3 }}</option>
      </select>
      {{ sentPt2 }}
      <select id="response-col" class="option" name="answer">
        <option disabled selected></option>
        <option value={{ COL1 }}>{{ COL1 }}</option>
        <option value={{ COL2 }}>{{ COL2 }}</option>
      </select>
      {{ sentPt3 }}
    </p>
    <button id="done" class="nodisplay" onchange="doneChange">Done</button>
  </div>
</div>
{{/ sentPt1 }}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @VMacuchS Glad to help. :)

Comment: Thanks for the commenting too, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try something like this:

```
var response_quant = false;
var response_shape = false;
var response_col = false;

$('#response-quant').change(function() {
    response_quant = true;
    if ( response_quant == true && response_shape == true && response_col == true ) {
  $('#done').removeClass('nodisplay');
}
});
$('#response-shape').change(function() {
    response_shape = true;
    if ( response_quant == true && response_shape == true && response_col == true ) {
  $('#done').removeClass('nodisplay');
}
});
$('#response-col').change(function() {
    response_col = true;
    if ( response_quant == true && response_shape == true && response_col == true ) {
  $('#done').removeClass('nodisplay');
}
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: That's a really smart idea, thanks. Unfortunately, though, it does not work. It might very well be the case that there's something elsewhere in my code which is preventing it from working, but so far no success.

Comment: Are you able to alert inside change event? Try to debug it. I think it should work.

Comment: Alert works. I get one pop-up window each time I submit an option (so one for each select).

Answer (score 0):

You could add an if-clause with:

```
if($('#response-quant').selectedIndex != 0 && $('#response-shape').selectedIndex != 0 && $('#response-col').selectedIndex != 0){
    $('#done').removeClass('nodisplay');
}
```

although I would suggest the .css()-method instead of removing the class

Comment: It doesn't work either. As for your suggestion, do you mean something like this:

    $('#done').css('display', 'none');

Comment: Exactly, you only change one css-entry this way and can keep the class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
HTML

```
<div class="sent nodisplay">
    <p class="answer-container dropdown-container">
    <p class="question">
        <select id="response-quant" class="option" name="answer" onchange="quantChange()">
            <option disabled selected></option>
            <option value={{ QUANT1 }}>{{ QUANT1 }}</option>
            <option value={{ QUANT2 }}>{{ QUANT2 }}</option>
        </select>
        <select id="response-shape" class="option" name="answer" onchange="shapeChange()">
            <option disabled selected></option>
            <option value={{ SHAPE1 }}>{{ SHAPE1 }}</option>
            <option value={{ SHAPE2 }}>{{ SHAPE2 }}</option>
            <option value={{ SHAPE3 }}>{{ SHAPE3 }}</option>
        </select>
        <select id="response-col" class="option" name="answer" onchange="colChange()">
            <option disabled selected></option>
            <option value={{ COL1 }}>{{ COL1 }}</option>
            <option value={{ COL2 }}>{{ COL2 }}</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <button id="done" onchange="doneChange" hidden>Done</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var quant = false;
    var shape = false;
    var col = false;
    function quantChange(){
        quant = true;
        if (quant == true && shape == true && col == true) {
            $('#done').show();
        }
    }
    function shapeChange() {
        shape = true;
        if (quant == true && shape == true && col == true) {
            $('#done').show();
        }
    }
    function colChange() {
        col = true;
        if (quant == true && shape == true && col == true) {
            $('#done').show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Weirdly enough, I get an error that quant/shape/colChange are not defined. Isn't function quant/shape/colChange() {...} supposed to define them?

Comment: I did. The solution Takit Isy has offered works though, so thanks very much for your help.